# How can I fold all cell in ipynb file with Vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter, fold, vscode-remote, ipynb

There is a "collapse all" hot key: ctrl+K ctrl+0, but this method can only fold current cell. Such like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYmxp.png)

And there is another hot key "Collapse all cell input" (no keys bound). Athough all cells can be collapsed, the contents of the cells will also be hidden. Such like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b75xY.png) (All cells have only one line, including markdown content, which is not the function I want)

In JetBrain DataSpell,  I can collapse all cells at once (not hide all cells). Such like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhdjD.png)

Version of Vscode: 1.80.1

I've tried everything in the keybindings about collapsing and expanding, but none seem to work

Comment: so you want to collapse all folding regions in all cells with a single action?